# AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR while downloading some images from web in WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack.
I am downloading articles and images from one web site. 80% images downloading without problem. But some images throwing error. I can see name of error in image_failed event.
I am downloading image like that:

```
 Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(img.Attributes["src"].Value));
```

I have searched google and found that this is really WTF problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good chance the referrer header is screwing you up. You need to issue the calls yourself (instead of relying on BitmapImage to download the file).

There's a handy snippet/utility that 'extends' xaml and makes it easier to do.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/08/04/wp7-mango-image-download-with-custom-referer-header.aspx

**Edit: Explanation**

A lot of sites block requests for images not coming from their sites. That way, if you have http://mysite.com and you link to images in http://cnn.com, they can block images directly linked and redirect them or something.

Now, the reason it works is that the browser controls all calls made from the  tag (or from any other mechanism such as AJAX) and it adds the REFERRER HTTP header saying where the request is coming from (http://mysite.com) - and then the cnn.com code can block it.

In .NET desktop, the Referrer header is not automatically added to the request - that means that the call would be blocked by some site that checks for an empty referrer and not for others that don't.

Switch to WP7/8 which is based on Silverlight. In Silverlight, the referrer is the site on which the Silverlight  control is hosted. So if you have a SL control running on http://mysite.com and it makes [any] http request, the referrer header will be automatically set for you to http://mysite.com. There's no way to control that afaik (for security reasons). Windows Phone, however, while based on SL, does not need to be bound by the same security constraints. However, when they "ported" the code to Windows Phone, they put some value into referrer into it - the value is actually the package location inside the phone (you can see this by using fiddler). It's literally some path (/apps/storage/[guid]) or something like that - I don't recall the exact value. To fix that, you go and set the referrer to the site on the HTTP headers making the request.

Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: But could you explain code to me? I have trouble to nunderstand why it worked

Comment: Added an explanation. Hope that helps.